# malloced char * object filled with random text and of an apparent different size

Tags: arrays, c, string, malloc

I have the following code, and am specifically having problems with the `print_file_results` function.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int bytes_flag,lines_flag, words_flag;
int arg_in;
static struct option long_opts [] = {
    {"bytes", no_argument, 0, 'c'},
    {"lines", no_argument, 0, 'l'},
    {0,0,0,0}
};

int count_bytes(const char *filename){
    FILE * file_stream;
    int byte_count = 0;

    file_stream = fopen(filename, "r");
    
    if (file_stream == NULL){
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
    }
    else{
        while (getc(file_stream) != EOF){
            byte_count ++;
        }
        fclose(file_stream);
    }
    return byte_count;
}

void print_file_results(const int bytes, const int lines, const int  words, const char *filename, const int size){
    char * results = malloc(size * 2 + 1);
    printf(results);
    printf("\n");
    char int_buffer[4];
    if (bytes != 0) {
        sprintf(int_buffer, "%d ", bytes);
        strcpy(results, int_buffer);
        printf(results);
        printf("\n");
    }
    if (lines != 0) { 
        //TODO
    }
    if (words != 0) {
        //TODO
    }
    printf("%s%s\n", results, filename);
    free(results);
    return;
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {

    while(1){
        arg_in = getopt_long (argc, argv, "cl", long_opts, NULL);

        if (arg_in == -1){
            break;
        }
        switch(arg_in){
            case 'c':
                printf("Byte count\n");
                bytes_flag = 1;
                break;
            case 'l':
                printf("Line count\n");
                lines_flag = 1;
                break;
            default:
                abort();
        }
    }

    if (optind < argc){
        while (optind < argc){
            int bytes_total = 0;
            int lines_total = 0;
            int words_total = 0;

            printf("Current file %s\n", argv[optind]);

            if ( bytes_flag ){
                bytes_total = count_bytes(argv[optind]);
            }
            if (lines_flag){
                continue;
            }
            if (words_flag){
                continue;
            }

            print_file_results(bytes_total, lines_total, words_total, argv[optind] , bytes_flag+lines_flag+words_flag);
            optind++;
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("No files given\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

The following output is received

```
❯ ./ccwc.o -c test.txt
Byte count
Current file test.txt
ation is committed to coa
342190 
342190 test.txt
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[1]    125314 IOT instruction (core dumped)  ./ccwc.o -c test.txt
```

My question is why does the random string appear in the `results` object that was malloced, and why does it appear to be more bytes than I allocated? I am also unsure why I am getting a stack smash, but first would like to understand my error in the object I am creating with malloc. Besides my confusion with the arrays initial values and the stack smash, the program seems to actually be printing the expected results with my test case, though obviously it crashing isn't ideal!

Comment: `malloc` doesn't clear memory to any particular value and the returned pointer cannot be treated as a 0 terminated string unless you assign something to the memory. `calloc` does fill the allocated block with 0.

Comment: As @RetiredNinja said, it doesn't clear memory, and the reason is performance.

Most of the time when we allocate memory, we start stuffing our data into it, which would render any pre-clearing of that memory a waste of time.

Comment: `sprintf(int_buffer, "%d ", bytes);` are you aware, that `bytes` mustn't be greater than 99? Otherwise you will cause buffer overflow as `int_buffer can only hold 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory returned from `malloc` is uninitialized.  So when you attempt to read the string, you're reading whatever garbage was left there.  And if there's no null byte set within the allocated memory, anything that expects it to be a string will read past the end of allocated memory, triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in your cases causes your code to crash.

So don't read uninitialized memory.

Comment: Is that why it also appears to be a longer string? I allocated, in this case 2 bytes, but when I print it just prints from the memory location referenced by the pointer and continues until it sees a \n?

Comment: @CalebRenfroe Until it sees a 0.

Comment: @CalebRenfroe The C language doesn't have many safety nets. If you give a `char*` to a function that expects `\0` to appear before it reads out of bounds, the language is fine with that. If you don't provide such a string to that function, your program has undefined behavior as dbush linked to. The language is very free when it comes to what you can do syntactically. You as a programmer must make sure that you don't provide addresses/ranges to functions that will make them read out of bounds.

Comment: Thank you everyone, this helps my understanding alot.